# EXCEL: Is there a simple way to have an excel chart match cell format based on conditional formatting?

Tags: excel, charts, conditional-formatting

I'm working a on a spreadsheet where I'm displaying the differences between budget and actual spent amount for multiple different business units. I've added a radio button that lets the user toggle between viewing these differences as a raw dollar-amount difference or as a percentage. I have conditional formatting so that when the radio button is set to "Percentages" the data is shown as percentages and vice versa with dollar amounts.

However, the one thing that does not toggle is the data labels and axis labels on my charts. I can't make it so that these update when the cells change from percentages to dollars. I can either have them so they are always shown as a percentage, always shown as a dollar amount, or just sit statically as a generic number.

Does anyone know a way to make this update easily? I likely could create a VBA solution but am trying to avoid putting too much code into this tool if I can help it, so I'd definitely like to lean towards a non-VBA solution.

Thanks so much in advance for any help!

Comment: I think you'll have to use VBA.

Comment: Ya, that's kind of the conclusion I was coming to. Thanks for the response!